# Coldfusion and async ajax requests

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

So I'm somewhat inexperienced with Coldfusion and can't seem to find a similar question to this one. We've got a coldfusion 2016 project and to date, we haven't really used async javascript requests for apis. So my question is, is there any risk of coldfusion failing to render pdfs correctly if we started to move towards async and promise logic?

I'm guessing there isn't and it will simply wait for all work to complete but need somewhat of a sanity check from people with greater expertise on the world of cf.

Comment: I've been using AngularJS for the past 3 years with Coldfusion on the back end, and haven't had any issues with calling cfc functions via http requests.

Comment: What kind of risks do you think async processing might add?

Comment: Please clarify `async javascript request for apis`. Do you want to make an ajax call to get an already created PDF from your own API endpoint? Are you building the PDF on the fly within a thread and you're worried it won't be ready when an ajax request asks for it?